# Error - "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present." while using SQLDataReader even if data is present

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005

I was trying to to use parameterized query with data reader when I get this error message "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."

But data is there is the reader!

[image]

Following is the line of code which performs this task

```
using (ConnectionManager connectionManager = new ConnectionManager())
{   
    string query = @"SELECT * FROM LoginTab WHERE username=@username " +
              "AND password=@password";

    List<SqlParameter> sqlParameterCollection = new List<SqlParameter>();
    sqlParameterCollection.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = userName });
    sqlParameterCollection.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = password });

    SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = connectionManager.ExecuteReader(query, CommandType.Text, sqlParameterCollection);

    String roles = sqlDataReader[0].ToString();
    return roles;
}
```

ExecuteReader function is defined in another class.

```
public SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(String strcmd, CommandType type, List<SqlParameter> Parametercollections)
{
    connnection = new SqlConnection(Connnectionstring);
    command = new SqlCommand(strcmd, connnection);
    command.CommandType = type;
    foreach (SqlParameter paras in Parametercollections)
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(paras);
    }
    try
    {
        connnection.Open();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (SqlException E)
    {

    }
    finally
    {

    }

    return reader;
}
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Where is reader defined?  It might be a scoping issue, or the reader may be closed when it gets to the point where you try to read it.

Comment: Not the solution, but you should remove the try/catch/finally so you can learn about any exceptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`, the `SqlDataReader` that it gives you is initially positioned *before* the first record. You must call `SqlDataReader.Read()` to move to the first record before attempting to access any data. `SqlDataReader.Read()` returns `true` if it was able to move to the first record; it returns `false` if there are no records.

```
if (sqlDataReader.Read())
{    
    String roles = sqlDataReader[0].ToString();
    return roles;
}
else
{
    // The user name or password is incorrect; return something else or throw an exception.
}
```

Comment: Good catch, but I'm still curious as to where `reader` is defined in the OP's code...

Answer (score 1):

You should either check `SqlDataReader.HasRows` is true, or advance with `SqlDataReader.Read()` until it return false

```
using(SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = connectionManager.ExecuteReader())
{
  String roles=null;
  if (sqlDataReader.Read())
    roles = sqlDataReader[0].ToString();
  return roles;
}
```

You need to use `using` or `sqlDataReader.Close()` upon exit to free the locked by reader connection.

Comment: Thanks Oleg +1 . The exact issue was that I never called sqlDataReader.Read()to position the reader to the first record