# How to get the value of sql (sum) query in textbox?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

i want to add sum of 2 rows into two strings respectively please help

its my function's coding all parameters are well n good but still getting an error

```
public void temporderentry(SqlConnection conn,SqlCommand comd)
    {
        string sql = "select SUM(productQuaintyInOrder)  ,SUM(cost)  from OrderProduct where orderID = " + oid; //oid is defined
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        comd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = comd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.HasRows)
        {
            cart = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
            totalpayment = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]);
        }
    }
```

here the error

```
+       base    {"Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."}    System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

Comment: Change while (dr.HasRows) to while (dr.Read())

Comment: Does your query return data ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8964028/3627578

Comment: i did that but no help

Comment: Well error message says everything.

Comment: is there ayn problem with my query and if yes please correct it